# How do I detect the Keyboard show/hide event occurence on Android browser

Tags: javascript, android

I am in a fix. I am not able to identify a way to capture the keyboard show/hide status on a mobile device browser.

Problem :

I have a popup on a form in which a Text Field is present. When the user taps on the text field the keyboard shows up pushing the popup on the form and eventually making the text field invisible.

Is there a way to identify the key board show/hide status???

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to reliably know when a keyboard is showing.  The one level of control you do have is you can set your app to pan or resize when the keyboard shows up.  If you set it to resize, it will recalculate your layout and shrink things so if fits the remaining screen.  If you choose pan, it will keep the same size and just slide up the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

you can find out keyboard show/hide inside your application,Try following code inside oncreate method,and pass your parent layout to view.

```
final View activityRootView = rellayLoginParent;
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout()
                    {
                        Rect r = new Rect();
                        // r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
                        activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                        //MyLog.w("height difference is", "" + heightDiff);
                        if (heightDiff > 100)
                            { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                                if(lytAppHeader.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                                    {
                                        lytAppHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                if(lytAppHeader.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                                    {
                                        lytAppHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    }
                            }

                    }
            });
```

Comment: I was asking for a event detection in Browser. So it would be in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no reliable way to do this in the browser.  The closest I have come is to listen for *focus* events and then temporarily listen for *resize* events.  If a resize occurs in the next < 1 second, it's very likely that the keyboard is up.

Apologies for the jQuery...

```
onDocumentReady = function() {
    var $document = $(document);
    var $window = $(window);
    var initialHeight = window.outerHeight;
    var currentHeight = initialHeight;

    // Listen to all future text inputs

    // If it's a focus, listen for a resize.
    $document.on("focus.keyboard", "input[type='text'],textarea", function(event) {

        // If there is a resize immediately after, we assume the keyboard is in.
        $window.on("resize.keyboard", function() {
            $window.off("resize.keyboard");
            currentHeight = window.outerHeight;
            if (currentHeight < initialHeight) {
                window.isKeyboardIn = true;
            }
        });

        // Only listen for half a second.
        setTimeout($window.off.bind($window, "resize.keyboard"), 500);
    });

    // On blur, check whether the screen has returned to normal
    $document.on("blur.keyboard", "input[type="text"],textarea", function() {
       if (window.isKeyboardIn) {
           setTimeout(function() {
               currentHeight = window.outerHeight;
               if (currentHeight === initialHeight) {
                   window.isKeyboardIn = false;
           }, 500); 
       }
    });
```

};